# How to disconnect request for API after time out?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis

I hosted a ASP.NET Core web API 6 in IIS 10. Due to huge number of requests coming for API, there is a time out error generated from the API.

How can I cancel requests after time out?. The problem is, even after time out worker processor works on the requests. How can I cancel worker processor request after time out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RequestAborted property of the HttpContext class in your controller actions. This property returns a CancellationToken that is triggered when the client disconnects or the request times out. You can pass this token to any async methods that support cancellation, such as Task.Delay or HttpClient.SendAsync. This way, you can cancel the request processing and free up the worker processor resources. For example, you can use the following code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get()
{
  // Get the cancellation token from the request context
  var cancellation = HttpContext.RequestAborted;

  // Pass the token to any async methods that support cancellation
  await database.FooAsync(cancellation);

  // Return the result
  return Ok("No timeout!");
}
```

Another solution is to use the WithRequestTimeout extension method from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http namespace in your endpoint routing. This method allows you to specify a custom timeout policy for each endpoint, and optionally a custom response to return when the timeout occurs. This way, you can cancel the request processing and free up the worker processor resources. For example, you can use the following code:

```
app.MapGet("/usepolicy", async (HttpContext context) =>
{
  try
  {
  // Do some long running operation
  await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), context.RequestAborted);
  }
  catch (TaskCanceledException)
  {
  throw;
  }
 return Results.Content("No timeout!", "text/plain");
}).WithRequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); // Specify the timeout policy
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. "var cancellation = HttpContext.RequestAborted" is fine. How do we execute cancellation?

Comment: You're welcome. To execute cancellation, you need to pass the cancellation token to any async methods that support cancellation, such as Task.Delay or HttpClient.SendAsync. These methods will throw a TaskCanceledException or an OperationCanceledException when the cancellation token is triggered. You can catch these exceptions and handle them accordingly in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to consider other factors, [recycle the App Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/) is the easiest way.

Comment: But How do we do this for time out only through the .net core API?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Isn't your request cancel requests?

Comment: I mean, How do we recycle app pool after time out?. suppose that our time out period is 20 seconds. Then How do we call recycle the app pool after that?

Comment: You can refer to this link about recycle application Pool: [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/780076/Recycle-Application-Pool-s-in-IIS-Server-Using-C).